# Is it possible to exclude or only follow certain friends in your Facebook wall feed?

Tags: facebook

I'd like to limit my wall feed in Facebook to only show the statuses or activity of certain friends and groups. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hover your mouse cursor over a news story posted by somebody you no longer wish to receive updates from - you should see the word 'Hide' appear in the top right corner.  Click the word 'Hide' and then select 'Hide NAME' to remove future updates from that person.

Alternatively, you can create lists of people e.g. friends, family, colleagues, members of a sports team etc by going to the 'Friends' menu on the left sidebar.  You can then select one of these lists to view only new stories and status updates from people in those lists.